# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined

Tags: reactjs

Getting `this is undefined` error. Tried searching for solution but didn't find any.

This same code is working fine on another page but don't know what's wrong here. Printing output of brands before setState is printing valid result.

```
class FindSponsors extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        db.ref("sponsor").once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
            let data = snapshot.val()
            let brands = []
            for (let brand in data) {
                brands.push({
                    name: data[brand].Name,
                    website: data[brand].Website
                })
            }
            this.setState({     //Error here
                data: brands
            })
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default FindSponsors;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the arrow function:

```js
db.ref("sponsor").once("value").then((snapshot) => { /*your function body here*/})
```

`this` keyword is nothing more than a link to an execution context. In your example above you "execute" function "in the callback".
Try reading [this](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc) to understand better how it works and how arrows functions are different from regular ones.

Comment: Doing ```db.ref("sponsor").on('value', (snapshot) => {``` solved it thnx

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you define your callback function in the `.then`, the context of this function changes and `this` will basically refer to the inside of the function.

Two solutions here:

1. Use the [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to change the value of `this` for your callback. It would be something like this:

```js
const callback = function (snapshot) {
    // Your callback logic
}
db.ref("sponsor").once("value").then(callback.bind(this));
```

2. Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They have the specificity to not have their own bindings of the `this` keyword. This would be like this:

```js
db.ref("sponsor").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    // Your callback logic
});
```